# Gmail on iOS and Gmail on Android rendering differently

Tags: android, html, ios, gmail, html-email

I have an email I'm writing using table-based layouts which, when sent to an email account, renders the rows in a "mobile-optimized" smaller form on Gmail for Android, but renders them full-width (and therefore with tiny text) on Gmail for iOS.

Any thoughts here on what might be going on? I know this isn't the clearest question, and I can't narrow it down to a certain set of html that's causing the difference. Googling also produced no obvious results.

```html
    <table width=100% cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="" class="">
        <tr width="100%">
            <td width="100%" style="
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #f1f1f1;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        " class="">
                
                
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width='100%' style='' align='' class="">
        
                    
    <tr style='' class=''>
        
                        
    <td width='' height='' style='
            width: 150px;
            min-width: 150px;
            line-height: 0;
        ' align='' valign='top' class='list-card__header' colspan='1'>
        
                            
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width='100%' style='' align='' class="">
        
                                
    <tr style='' class=''>
        
                                    
    <td width='' height='' style='
            width: 150px;
            max-width: 150px;
            height: 75px;
            line-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        background-color:#dedede' align='center' valign='middle' class='list-card__image-wrapper' colspan='1'>
        
                                        <img class="list-card__image" src="https://cdn.evbstatic.com/s3-build/perm_001/f8c5fa/django/images/discovery/default_logos/4.png" style="
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 150px;
            height: 75px;
        " border="0" />
                                    
    </td>
    
                                
    </tr>
    
                            
    </table>
    
                        
    </td>
    
                        
    <td width='*' height='' style='
            padding-left: 15px;
            min-width: 150px;
        ' align='left' valign='top' class='list-card__body' colspan='1'>
        
                            <div class="list-card__date" style="
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            color: #343434;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            min-width: 150px;
            width: 150px;
        ">
                                Sat, Dec 31
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-card__title" style="
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 36px;
            max-height: 36px;
            color: #333333;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 700;
            line-height: 18px;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            min-width: 150px;
        ">
                                Hunger Plus, Inc.
                            </div>
                            <div style="
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            color: #8c8c8c;
            min-width: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 20px;
            max-height: 20px;
        ">
                                Hunger Plus, Inc.
                            </div>
                        
    </td>
    
                    
    </tr>
    
                
    </table>
    
            
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a lot of ideas of what could be going wrong :) Can you post a small example of the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding, but it looks like changing the first line:

```
<table width=100% cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="" class="">
```

to this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
```

solves the issue. The `<table width=100% ...>` was causing the layout to be full width. The edited code makes the email 100%, but only up to 600px, so the email will be wider on large screens and scale down on smaller ones.

Answer (score -1):

HTML is not graphical format, guaranteeing pixel perfect result on every platform. For something like that PDF is lot more close (or images, with loss of text information completely).

HTML is "Hyper Text Markup Language", so it was mostly designed to transfer text content, with additional marks helping to process (render/use) the content.

CSS made it somewhat more predictable in terms of graphical output, but it's still not very safe to assume anything (for example web of bank I use looks broken on my desktop, as I use enforced minimal font size, which breaks a bit the layout design of their tables, offsetting value lines out of sync with labels).

But this is HTML, and you are talking about email. As long as you aim only at gmail, at least you can check what the result looks like. But in case you want to send proper universal email (without assuming the receiver is reading it with Gmail app), you actually should rather send valid plain-text version (together with HTML one). The HTML extension is not even part of standard, and there's still about ~3% of people using text-only mail clients (like me).

So what is your problem, the tiny text? And is your email supposed to be read mostly on mobile phone screens? Then create the table with fewer columns, so it will be narrow enough? Or check out some CSS magic to create different variants of layout for devices reporting different screen width.

Either way, you can't expect pixel perfect rendering, as each device has different screen, or the user may be running the mail app in window only, or the user can enforce different font sizes, etc.

So it's normal, that different device/application renders your HTML differently, and it shouldn't pose any problem to you, if your HTML is reasonably designed.